# How can I link a file other than Public directory in Express with EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

For example, 
in `Ejs`view file I want to link a file source that is coming from the media folder. Not a Public folder.

```
<audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="../../../media/Song.mp3">
</audio>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another `static`-[middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for your `media` directory:

```
app.use(express.static('media'));
```

Comment: But that's how anybody can access through URL. I do not want that.
Is there any way? I am a brand new express developer.. Help please :)

Comment: Your browser actually does the exact same thing - the resource needs to be accessible publicly :)